# prevent auto focus on window.open for ios?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, window.open

I have the following click handler in an admin area I am working on.  Basically there is a table of all user accounts on the site and I can click on a login button for each user to login AS that user in a new window.  This is for support reasons and I need to do things in their account.

To avoid popup warnings in the browser and so it actually works in mobile safari... I am opening a blank new window 'UserLogin' on click... the ajax runs and returns a response where I open the url on true or write a message on false.

Everything works fine in the browsers I have tested except mobile safari (ios).  On click the focus shifts to my new blank window and 'halts'.  If I go back to my original window the ajax kicks in and focus is taken back to the new window where the url or message is loaded.  So, it appears I need a way to prevent the focus changing on the original `window.open('', 'UserLogin');`.

Any ideas?  I know its a bit of a hack to do this, but you cannot open a new window from ajax... browsers will throw popup warnings and ios won't even do anything.  The new window needs to be attached to a click event directly to prevent this which is why I am doing it the way I am.

```
// user login in new window
$('#datatable').on('click', '.dtLogin', function () {

    //open blank window to prevent popup warnings in browser
    window.open('', 'UserLogin');

    var data = {
      'account_id': $(this).parents('tr').attr('id')
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/test/process/p_user_login.php',
        data: data,
        dataType : 'json'
    }).done(function (response) {

        if (response.success)
        {                   
            window.open('http://www.test.com/', 'UserLogin');

            // show success message
            $("#dtAlert").html('<div class="alert alert-dt alert-info alert-dismissable"><button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" type="button"></button><strong>Success!</strong> &nbsp;You have been logged in as user \'<b>'+response.username+'</b>\'.</div>');                            
            alertCount = 0;

            // show success toast
            toastr.info('You have been logged in as user \'<b>'+response.username+'</b>\'.');
        } 
        else
        {
            // show error message
            $("#dtAlert").html('<div class="alert alert-dt alert-danger alert-dismissable"><button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" type="button"></button><strong>Error!</strong> &nbsp;An error has occurred. &nbsp;Please contact support.</div>');                         
            alertCount = 0;

            // show error toast
            toastr.error('An error has occurred. &nbsp;Please contact support.', 'Error');

            loginWindow.document.open();
            win.document.write('Error : Could not login to the user account.');
            win.document.close();

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried 'starting' the ajax request before opening the other window? I mean just put it below the `$.ajax().done()`. It may work since `$.ajax` is asynchronous.

Comment: I think I mentioned this in my post... the window open has to be directly attached to a click event.  If not, it will show popup warnings or not even be processed as is the case with ios.

Comment: Yeah, and I get that. It will still be inside the click-event, just not at the very top. `$.ajax` is asynchronous (basically means that the script doesn't wait for it to finish before running the next command). I thought that it could work if it just get's to _start_ the ajax right before the window opened that it may be executed as well.

Comment: Like this: http://pastebin.com/yZGHJ79E

Comment: I wish... unfortunately that has the same effect as my current method.  On click the new blank window is opened with focus.  I have to return to the original page then and it has a redirect type action where it immediately goes back to the new window and loads my url.  That is only for mobile safari though... regular browsers work fine just as mine does.

Comment: Shoot... It was worth a try. I will get back to you if I something pops up :)

Comment: Thanks... appreciate it.  I remember coming across this before where you couldn't open a window in ajax... I guess it was to prevent spamming and what not, but takes away the use aspects.